# dependent text field validation issue

Tags: validation-rule

I'm writing a validation rule for dependent text field. If user has selected "Other" option then must fill text field. ---> done like below

But if any value choosen except "Other" don't allow user to fill text field / don't allow user to save record with text field value.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c, 'other - please specify'),
    ISBLANK(ET_Frequency_Period__c)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND(
   OR(
      AND(ISPICKVAL(ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c, 'other - please specify'),
          ISBLANK(ET_Frequency_Period__c)),
      AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c, 'other - please specify')),
          NOT(ISBLANK(ET_Frequency_Period__c)))
    )
)
```

This validation rule will fire when either of the following scenarios occurs:

- The user has selected "Other - please specify" option in the ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c picklist field, but has left the ET_Frequency_Period__c text field blank.
- The user has selected any other option in the ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c picklist field, but has entered some value in the ET_Frequency_Period__c text field.

This will ensure that the user fills the text field only when the picklist field is "Other - please specify", and leaves it blank otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following formula to check your requirements.

```
OR(NOT(ISPICKVAL(ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c, 'other - please specify')),
ISBLANK(ET_Frequency_Period__c)
)
```

If one of the above conditions is true then it will throw the validation error.

As per the requirement, the record is saved only when the Picklist "ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c" has the value  "other - please specify" and the text field "ET_Frequency_Period__c" is not blank.